# Showing $\text{sinc}(x)$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have been having some trouble proving continuity of $\text{sinc}(x)$ on $[0, \infty)$, specifically, at $x = 0$, where $\text{sinc}(x) = \cases{\frac{\sin(x)}{x} &x>0 \\1 &x=0}$.

On $(0,\infty)$ I just showed $1/x$ is continuous, and, taking $\sin(x)$ continuous, $\text{sinc}(x)$ should be continuous as a composition of two continuous functions. However, at $x=0$ I haven't been able to give the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof (as considering $|\frac{\sin(x)}{x} - 1|$ gets me nowhere), nor to use the sequential characterisation of continuity.

Would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: What's the definition of $\mathrm{sinc}$?

Comment: $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$ gets you home fast.

Comment: Remember that $\sin$ is differentiable at $x=0$ so that $\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(0)}{x-0}$ has a limit when $x$ goes to $0$.

Comment: @Bebop Oh, I see, I may use the fact that $\text{sinc}(x)$ is continuous at $0$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \text{sinc}(x) = \text{sinc}(0) = 1$, and then expanding this expression to get equality with $\cos{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that $\mathrm{sinc}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, since it is a composite of two continuous functions.

To prove continuity of $\mathrm{sinc}$ at $x=0$, you must show that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \mathrm{sinc}(x) = \mathrm{sinc}(0)$$

Comment: Cheers, I think I have got it thanks to you and @Bebop.